# In a low water pressure area, why would water from a shower take several seconds to flow after the shower is turned on?

Tags: shower

I have an unvended hot water cylinder; due to low water pressure where I live, I have a pump installed which assists the pressure when using my shower. When I first go to turn my shower on in the morning, it usually takes around 10 seconds from the time that the shower is turned on until any water is produced and the pump is kicked into action; however, if I then turn the shower off and back on, water begins to flow immediately. What would be the reason for this?

Comment: are you sure that the pump kicks in after the water comes out of the shower head?

Comment: do you have other leaks (like a dripping faucet elsewhere?) Do you hear air when the water is not being produced for the first 10s? Have you tried other faucets or sinks before the shower in the morning? Please try something else tomorrow first and see if it does the same thing

Comment: Is this low pressure system for your shower part of a tub also? If the water is being diverted up to a shower head it may take that long to fill the pipe, turn the pressure off the pipe is still full so it flows when turned on. Other than that we would need to know more about the controls on the pump.

Comment: @Ed - This sounds like the most reasonable answer and makes perfect sense - feel free to submit an answer if you like. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested:
Is this low pressure system for your shower part of a tub also? If the water is being diverted up to a shower head it may take that long to fill the pipe, turn the pressure off the pipe is still full so it flows when turned on. Other than that we would need to know more about the controls on the pump.

Comment: I used to have a crappy submersible pump that I used when my basement flooded.  If I ran the house out up the stairs before turning it on, it couldn't move the water to the required height.  If I started it in the basement and walked it up while it was running, it could (plus a few feet.)  This situation could be similar.

Comment: Jimmy it sounds like the motor you had could not push the head pressure. But having it running and raising the discharge did not require the motor to start under load, I have hydraulic systems and large air compressors that won’t start under load but relieve the pressure and put them under load and they pump fine.

Comment: @Ed - Thank you. This pump is purely used to power this shower, but the reasoning you gave makes logical sense.